How can I mock Panache.withTransaction()?
I'm using QuarkusComponentTest and I have some service methods that I need to do unit tests.
Since we moved to hibernate reactive we introduce the Panache.withTransaction like on the method below:
    public Uni<List<Owner>> listOwnerObjects() {
        return Panache.withTransaction(() -> ownerRepository.findWithPagination())
                .onItem().transform(
                        list -> list.stream().map(i -> joinMapper.mapOwnerEntityToDto(i, joinMapperContext)).toList());
    }

I'm using @InjectMock to inject the repository and PanacheQuery.
But I don't know how to deal with this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current Vertx context found
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.SessionOperations.vertxContext(SessionOperations.java:191)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.SessionOperations.withSession(SessionOperations.java:110)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.runtime.SessionOperations.withTransaction(SessionOperations.java:88)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.Panache.withTransaction(Panache.java:52)


Have you read https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#mocking ?

Well, I read but that page is talking about @QuarkusTest and not QuarkusComponentTest

Fair enough, but did you try the mocking stuff mentioned there?
